# Error retrieving string from my array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am working on downloading a string from my database to into my program. I believe all is going well except where I am trying to take the string FROM my array and save it to a NSString. I have uploaded a screenshot of my breakpoint. after the line  `NSString *test=[[items objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"vid"];` I get an error that [BHarDetails objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd66680'. Im not sure why that is. BHarDetails is only an NSObject where i define vid as a NSString. I also have another NSObject file where i assign the database field link to the variable vid and an array is returned, Si I am not sure exacctly why this error is occuring. Would appreciate any help offered in solving this error and taking my link from the vid variable and items array to a string.

Thank you

```
-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items {  
        NSURL *URL;
        for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++) {
            NSString *test=[[items objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"vid"];
            URL=[NSURL URLWithString:test];
        }
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [_webPlayer loadRequest:request];
}
```

2nd object

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
            // Create an array to store the locations
            NSMutableArray *_transfer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            // Parse the JSON that came in
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];  
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {
                NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];
                BHarDetails *dbfield= [[BHarDetails alloc] init];
                dbfield.vid = jsonElement[@"link"];
                // Add this question to the transfer array
                [_transfer addObject:dbfield];
            }
             if (self.delegate) {
                [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_transfer];
            }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saving a NSDictionary object in that array, you're saving a "`BHarDetails`" object.

So trying to do a "`objectForKey`" call on your "`BHarDetails`" object, which causes the crash as "`BharDetails`" isn't a subclass of NSDictionary (as far as I can tell).

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
BHarDetails *bObject = [items objectAtIndex:i];
if(bObject)
{
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:bObject.vid];
}
```

Comment: Speedy reply, an it fixed it. however. There have been times when I have used this code and I was able to get the string value. And I am pretty sure they were array as well. Example          for(int i=0;i<[JSONarray count];i++)
    {
 
        NSNumber *latitude = [[JSONarray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"];  works fine

Comment: that's because in those cases you were adding NSDictionary objects to your array.

Comment: NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSArray *JSONarray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

Comment: This is the array, where are the dictionaryObjects. I seeems the same to me

Comment: Maybe there, from JSON, it's dictionary objects.  But in the case of "`BharDetails`", you're definitely not putting NSDictionary objects into your array.

Comment: oh JSon are dictionary objects, ah ok thanks. got it

Comment: they *can* be dictionary objects. They might be other arrays, or they might be NSNumber or NSString objects. Ya never can be quite 100% certain what the server might send your direction via JSON.